# How can we find 2 timestamp difference in minutes using PySpark SQL?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, bigdata, apache-spark-sql

SQL:
DATEDIFF(mi, ClockInUTC_End,ClockInUTC_Snd) TimeinMinutes

I want to its alternative in PySpark SQL.
spark.sql("")

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using unix_timestamp function, which bascially converts to UNIX epoch value which is in UTC. Please refer below code.

```
spark.sql("""
SELECT  "2019-12-18 06:30:00" AS ClockInUTC_End,
        "2019-12-18 06:00:00" AS ClockInUTC_Snd, 
        CAST((unix_timestamp("2019-12-18 06:30:00", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") 
                - unix_timestamp("2019-12-18 06:00:00", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))/60 AS INT) AS Diff_In_Minutes  
""").show(20,False)


Output :
+-------------------+-------------------+---------------+
|ClockInUTC_End     |ClockInUTC_Snd     |Diff_In_Minutes|
+-------------------+-------------------+---------------+
|2019-12-18 06:30:00|2019-12-18 06:00:00|30             |
+-------------------+-------------------+---------------+
```